# PHP multiple form validation issue

Tags: php, validation

I have multiple forms on the same page that use the function generate_token(). I can only get one form to work if its the only form with the generate_token() function. I want to be able to have multiple forms on the same web page each with there own generate_token() function. But I just cant seem to get it to work when multiple forms on the same web page all have the generate_token() function. Can some one help me solve this problem. Thanks.

PHP Functions

```
function real_domain(){
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
        return false;
    } else {
        $referer_host = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);
        $server_host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

        return ($referer_host == $server_host) ? true : false;
    }
}

function request_is_post(){
    return filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === 'POST';
}

function token(){
    return md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
}

function generate_token(){
    $token = token();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    $_SESSION['token_time'] = time();
    return $token;
}

function destroy_token(){
    $_SESSION['token'] = null;
    $_SESSION['token_time'] = null;
    return true;
}

function valid_token(){
    if(isset($_POST['token']) && !is_array($_POST['token'])){
        if(isset($_POST['token'])){
            $user_token = $_POST['token'];

            if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){
                $stored_token = $_SESSION['token'];
                return $user_token === $stored_token;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        foreach($_POST['token'] as $token){
            if(isset($token)){
                $user_token = $token;

                if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){
                    $stored_token = $_SESSION['token'];
                    return $user_token === $stored_token;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

function token_time(){
    $expire_token = 60 * 60 * 24;

    if(isset($_SESSION['token_time'])){
        $stored_time = $_SESSION['token_time'];
        return ($stored_time + $expire_token) >= time();
    } else {
        destroy_token();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Form Validation

```
if(real_domain()){
    if(request_is_post()){
        if(valid_token()){
            if(token_time()){
                $errors = '';
                $success = '';

                if(isset($_POST['submit_comment'])){
                        $post_id = filter_numbers($_POST['post_id']);
                        $comment = filter_members_string($_POST['comment']);

                        if(!empty($_POST['comment'])){
                            if(empty($comment)){
                                $errors .= '<p class="error">&#x2731; Error.</p>';
                            } else {
                                if(strlen(html_entity_decode($comment, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8')) >= 5001){
                                    $errors .= '<p class="error">&#x2731; Error.</p>';
                                } else {
                                    if($_POST['comment'] !== $comment){
                                        $errors .= '<p class="error">&#x2731; Error.</p>';
                                    } else {
                                        $success .= '<p class="success">&#x2714; Your comment was posted.</p>';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if(!empty($success) && empty($errors)){
                            $query = "INSERT `post_comments` (`post_id`, `member_id`, `comment`, `date_created`)
                                      VALUES('$post_id ', '" . $_SESSION['member_id'] . "', '$comment_value', NOW())";
                            mysqli_query(database(), $query);
                        }

                        if(empty($success) && empty($errors)){
                            $errors .= '<p class="error">&#x2731; Your comment was not posted.</p>';
                        }           
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML Form

```
    <form method="post" action="" class="post-form">
        <fieldset>
            <ol>
                <li><label for="post-info-2" class="post-header">Post</label></li>
                <li><textarea name="post" id="post-info-2"></textarea></li>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>  
            <ol>
                <li><input type="submit" name="submit_post" value="Submit Post" class="submit-post" /><input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo generate_token(); ?>" /></li>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <form method="post" action="" class="post-form">
        <fieldset>
            <ol>
                <li><label for="post-info" class="post-header">Post</label></li>
                <li><textarea name="post" id="post-info"></textarea></li>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>  
            <ol>
                <li><input type="submit" name="submit_post" value="Submit Post" class="submit-post" /><input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo generate_token(); ?>" /></li>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: you cannot have the same id on both forms

Comment: sorry about that the id= should post-form-1 and so on.

Comment: the problem is, in your `generate_token()` it is setting the session token. This means the last time the function gets called that will set the session therefore the other times its overwritten

Comment: Turn your `$_SESSION['token']` and `$_SESSION['token_time']` into an array use `in_array()`?

Comment: I still can't seem to get it to work :(

Comment: Lets see your updated code. You need to change the `generate_token`, `destroy_token`, and `validate_token` functions to accommodate this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code,

```
function generate_token(){
    $token = token();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    $_SESSION['token_time'] = time();
    return $token;
}
```

`$_SESSION['token']` gets overwritten every time you call the function. You need to change it into an array, maybe even an associative array.

```
function generate_token() {
  $token = token();
  $_SESSION['token'][] = array('value' => $token, 'time' => time());
  return $token;
}
```

then, when you check it, you can keep the number of tokens to a reasonable level by using `array_shift()` or simply delete the token key in `$_SESSION`

for your `function valid_token()` you could use PHP command `in_array()` to look for it.

If you're doing this for CSRF protection, you're usually better off using code that has been around the block, tried and true.  Check out OWASP for info about how to do CSRF protection.